# Cookies for a 3 level collapsable jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using this script to store informations about expanded and collapsed menu levels:

```
    $('#menu li:has(ul) a').click(function() {
$(this).next().toggle();
if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $.cookie($(this).text(), 'expanded');
}

if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
    $.cookie($(this).text(), 'collapsed');
}
});


$('.item').each(function() {
    var verticalNav = $.cookie( $(this).children('a').text() );
    if (verticalNav == 'expanded') {
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    }
});
```

Works fine with 2 levels menu. For example:

```
<ul>
<li>item 1
    <li>item 1.1</li>
</li>
```

But when I put a third level:

```
<ul>
<li>item 1
    <li>item 1.1
        <li>item 1.1.1</li>
    </li>
</li>
```

If I click only in level 2, when the page is refresh, level 3 is showed.

Answer (score 1):

Note your current solution only stores the last clicked item, not the full list.

I would suggest putting ids on each item, then storing an array of ids for the expanded items. Then, on page load, collapse everything, then expand the items in the array. Or store the collapsed items and start with everything expanded, whichever works for your design. Iterating through all of the items and comparing the text every time will get slower as you get more items.

I've put together a small sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geSZz/13/).

I went a little overboard and created an object for tracking which items are expanded. I'm also using the [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) rather than cookies; this is a personal preference. To change it to use cookies, just replace "store.get" or "store.set" with "$.cookie".